# Calling Task.Delay(50) frequently in a loop. Can this lead to a memory leak?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, memory-leaks, timer

In summary.
I have ASP.NET Core 6 Rest API project with a BackgroundService that is performing some work every 50 ms. For example:

```
public class DemoWorker : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Do work
            Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(50, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Recently, I noted the following issue reported by the ReSharper Dynamic Program Analysis (DPA) worker.

> Small Object Heap: Allocated 8.1 MB (8500792 B), max: 100.2 MB
> (105041568 B) of type System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer by
> DemoWorker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(uint, CancellationToken) at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan, CancellationToken) at
> DemoWorker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken) in <SOURCE_CODE_FILE_NAME>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext,
> ContextCallback, Object) at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1<System.__Canon,StartupHook+d__3>.MoveNext(Thread)
> at
> System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox,
> bool) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object) at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetResult() at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task+DelayPromise.CompleteTimedOut() at
> System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(bool) at
> System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() at
> System.Threading.UnmanagedThreadPoolWorkItem.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at
> System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

I read several articles on this. Most of them are saying that this is not a problem and I don't need to do anything special, or to dispose the task.

But one of the articles says that If I'm creating Task.Delay() calls faster than they're ending, then I will have a memory leak!

So my question is should I worry about this or just ignore it ?

Comment: Since you're awaiting it you should only be creating one at a time, unless you have multiple calls to this worker running together and even then I don't think it's going to be a problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal timer, eg a `System.Threading.Timer` ?

Comment: Note that this will not perform some work every 50 ms, but 50ms+ time the work takes (though it can be ok).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using the default Worker template code that is generated when you create a new WorkerService project in Visual Studio. I will consider replacing the while() + Task.Delay combination with a timer.

Comment: That code is just meant for demonstration. The [Timed background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) section in [Background Tasks with Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) uses a timer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already changed the code with one of the suggested approach with PeriodicTimer and will see the result.

Comment: The question is poorly stated: on one side there is no known memory leak issue with Task.Delay (when used correctly). The code example is the correct pattern. Sure if someone "creating Task.Delay() calls faster than they're ending" they would shoot themselves so to say and leak memory until they stop creating those Tasks. There would be other issues with the application though, for instance the threadpool could become exhausted rendering the application non-responsive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class for this purpose you can use as well.

```cs
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
{
    // Do work
    Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now);
}
```

But due to the operating system's architecture, time-related tasks are not %100 reliable.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/comparison-of-microsoft-windows-tools-for-waiting-time-management/

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

No, this pattern of usage should **not** cause any memory leak. The `Task` object created by the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) method, and all of its internal parts, should be eligible for garbage collection immediately after the completion of the task. There should be nothing that holds the garbage collector from recycling those objects.

In case you find that there is an unusually high number of `TimerQueueTimer` objects that are surviving multiple subsequent garbage collections, you might have found a bug in the .NET standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: I might rather use the new `PeriodicTimer` as it should be memory leak resistant according to this [article](https://www.ilkayilknur.com/a-new-modern-timer-api-in-dotnet-6-periodictimer).

Comment: There is no leak in what is presented in the question therefore there is no need to solve anything.